# The type or namespace name 'ViewModel' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, mvvm, namespaces

I have installed GalaSoft's MVVMLight to my project. I have used one file, replaced it and then deleted the  ViewModel directory since I don't need it anymore. Now I get the following error in App.g.cs file.

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'ViewModel' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'CodeFirstMVVM.App' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users...\CodeFirstMVVM\CodeFirstMVVM.App\obj\Debug\App.g.cs 12  25  CodeFirstMVVM.App

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: ` and then deleted the ViewModel directory since I don't need it anymore`

Comment: just put the files back from the original source and only remove any file when you are sure that you or the project don't really need them.